# Error: [Reanimated] `valueUnpacker` is not a worklet, js engine: hermes. ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: android, react-native

> Error: [Reanimated] `valueUnpacker` is not a worklet, js engine:
> hermes  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.
> This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Suddenly getting this error and unable to install and run app, deleted node_modules folder several times, executed npm install and npm run android serveral times but project not getting build.